# How do I split vim space evenly without changing file explorer size in my .vimrc?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

This is basically what I want to happen:

- Open vim with ‘vim .’
- Upon opening a file, file explorer should be vertically resized to 30 automatically (or whatever size so that it will be on the left side and small, 30 just seems to work for me when I do ':vertical resize') and STAY THAT WAY, no matter what. The file opened will take up the majority of the screen so I can code comfortably.

  ```
  |-explorer|-----------------------file-------------------------|
  |-explorer|-----------------------file-------------------------|
  |-explorer|-----------------------file-------------------------|
  |-explorer|-----------------------file-------------------------|
  |-explorer|-----------------------file-------------------------|
  |-explorer|-----------------------file-------------------------|
  |-explorer|-----------------------file-------------------------|
  |-explorer|-----------------------file-------------------------|
  ```
- Upon opening a new file, the file explorer should REMAIN THE SAME SIZE and vertically split the remaining space in half.

  ```
  |-explorer|-----------file-----------|------------file------------|
  |-explorer|-----------file-----------|------------file------------|
  |-explorer|-----------file-----------|------------file------------|
  |-explorer|-----------file-----------|------------file------------|
  |-explorer|-----------file-----------|------------file------------|
  |-explorer|-----------file-----------|------------file------------|
  |-explorer|-----------file-----------|------------file------------|
  |-explorer|-----------file-----------|------------file------------|
  ```

The key is that the file explorer DOES NOT change size. It is constant. The file explorer has been extremely stubborn for me in this regard, and I think it would be incredibly convenient if I can let the file explorer remain a constant small size while opening files splits the remaining space evenly. What should I should I add to my .vimrc to make this possible?

As a stretch goal, I would also like to try this:

Ideally, I would like to complete this

- the next file opened should be horizontally split.
- the fourth file should be horizontally split.

This will produce 4 even quarters of coding space with a file explorer on the left size.

[image: Here's the vimrc directly related to window sizes and what not.]

Comment: Netrw is not really designed for that use case. I don't think even the "recently" added `:Lexplore` can be made to work like that. If that's really important for you I would suggest for alternatives more explicitly designed to work like the side explorers in conventional programs.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/